# Why can't I bind a TCP socket to another IP address?

Tags: c#, ip-address, nettcpbinding, tcpsocket

At customer's site, the following piece of code is working like a charm:

```
private IPEndPoint GetCurrentServerIpAddress()
{           
    ...
    return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.13.9"), 12714);
}
var IPAddress = GetCurrentServerIpAddress();
_socket.Bind(IPAddress);
```

As I need to solve a bug on this customer's site, I'm trying to start the program on my own PC. For that, I would like to use another testing computer (all be it a virtual machine) with IP address "10.0.1.60"), where I want to do the same thing (but obviously with that new IP address:

```
private IPEndPoint GetCurrentServerIpAddress()
{           
    ...
    return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.1.0.60"), 12714);
}
var IPAddress = GetCurrentServerIpAddress();
_socket.Bind(IPAddress);
```

This, however, is not working: I always fall into a `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException`, mentioning "The requested address it not valid in its context".

I clearly see that "192.168.xxx.yyy" and "10.0.1.zzz" are different (kinds of) addresses, which might cause this problem.

What can I do in order to avoid that error message and be able to send TCP messages from my testing machine?

**Edit: the "ipconfig" of my PC**
The last comment mentioned a condition on the interfaces on my computer (which is a Windows-10 computer). As I have no idea how to interpret this comment, hereby the `ipconfig` command result:

```
Prompt>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet 4:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : company.int
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4c66:9ac5:dbd0:656%25
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.3.19
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.3.254

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 1:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe60::b53a:f868:31d0:e5a9%5
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.133.11
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe60::332e:9c68:4e2d:ceb7%27
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.11
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Talk2m-eCatcher:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 9:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 10:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Comment: IP addresses have two types.  One type that is on the public internet and others that are private behind firewalls.  IP addresses starting with 10 are private.  The solution is to put your test code on a public domain.

Comment: ^ [Private IPv4 ranges](https://www.ibm.com/docs/it/networkmanager/4.2.0?topic=translation-private-address-ranges)

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies. Do you know a away to treat my "10." IP address as a public one?

Comment: The `addressFamily` seems to be `Internetwork`, to which do I need to change this? (Or doesn't it make any difference?)

Comment: @DarkBee: I don't get it anymore: JdWeng mentioned the "10." address to be private, but your URL mentions both to be private, all be it in different so-called "classes" (10.xxx are "class A" while "192.168.xxx" seem to be "class C"). Is that class difference causing the exception?

Comment: You can bind to a public or private IP so long as an interface on your machine has it assigned. It shouldn't matter what range it falls into.

Comment: @jhmckimm: I don't know how to check your comment, hence I've added the `ipconfig` command result to my question.

Comment: @Dominique yeah, so try binding to `10.1.3.19` and it should work. `10.1.0.60` isn't assigned to your machine so you can't bind to it.

Comment: @Dominique I've added that link just as a reference, It's correct you have a private IP range per class, but that's out-of-scope on SO

Comment: [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) was introduced in *1993*. It's frankly ridiculous that documentation or user interfaces still talk of the network classes.